# Layout: OnePage apenas com HTML e CSS (com transition)

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um layout "*OnePage*", entretanto gostaria de faze-lô apenas com CSS e HTML. A ideia é quando o usuário clicar em next o mesmo será deslocado para a "section 01", isso já esta feito, porém não estou conseguindo colocar o efeito `trasition` para que haja "fluidez" quando se muda de seção, como se a pagina rolasse para baixo e não simplesmente pular para a próxima seção.

Tipo esse efeito do site [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/br/home)

OBS: achei algumas soluções usando `input radio e label`, porém acredito que deva existir alguma maneira mais direta.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.container-center {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 350%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  .text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 50%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

nav {
  width: inherit;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

#hero {
  width: inherit;
  height: 610px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

footer {
  width: inherit;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

#section-01 {
  height: 700px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container-center"></div>
</nav>

<section id="hero">
  <div class="container-center">
    <span class="text">Section Hero</span>
    <a href="#section-01" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</section>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-center"></div>
</footer>

<section id="section-01">
  <div class="container-center">
    <span class="text">Section - 01</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem como fazer só com HTML e CSS sim, vc pode usar o `scroll-behavior: smooth;` no css do `html {}`

Veja o exemplo abaixo para entender melhor.

```css
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}     
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.container-center {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 350%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  .text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 50%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

nav {
  width: inherit;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

#hero {
  width: inherit;
  height: 610px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

footer {
  width: inherit;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

#section-01 {
  height: 700px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <div class="container-center"></div>
  </nav>
  
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="container-center">
      <span class="text">Section Hero</span>
      <a href="#section-01" class="next">Next</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-center"></div>
  </footer>
  
  <section id="section-01">
    <div class="container-center">
      <span class="text">Section - 01</span>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @RobisonAleixo legal jovem, mas se atente que com essa técnica é complicado ajustar a altura que o conteúdo para antes do topo da janela. Com JS é mais fácil de controlar isso

Comment: Tah por aí?....

Comment: @dvd diga, agora estou, se ainda estiver precisando me dá um toque